# How to create users database using Auth0

Tags: c#, database, authentication

I need to implement a database for users for my desktop application. I have done some databases in sql manager on university, but I found out that `Autoh0` should be able to do it easier and in a better way, but I haven't found any good tutorials for doing that.

Is there anyone who uses `Autoh0` and could give me an advice on creating database and connecting to `login/password`? I tried a few things, but just can't figure out how to do it specifically for desktop app with `c#`.

Comment: don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: Well.. I understand that everyone uses sql datebases on the servers, but I thought that this might be another option and thats why I asked since I haven't seen this question yet.

Comment: MySQL is open source, if you really want to make your own DB feel free to take a look at the source code.

Comment: How can I make a user datebase without creating my own DB?

Comment: just ask the user to install the DB such as MySQL, SqlServer, Oracle DB or you can just include in memory DBs such as SqlLite

Comment: The things is I dont want every user to install anything but the program since there will be more than few users.

Comment: SqlLite is your only option in such case then. Implementing your own DB and make it efficient is probably gonna take you couple years or more